# Trying to run a loop for exactly one second, but the loop runs infinitely. why?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

i am changing the value of 'aa' after 1 second, but the loop continues to execute.

```
let aa = true;

setTimeout(function () {
  aa = false;
}, 1000);

for (; aa; ) {
  console.log('aaa');
}
```

Comment: Javascript runs on a single thread. Since the thread is busy actively running your loop, it can't also call the timeout function at the same time.

Comment: Here's a handy video to expand on @JoachimIsaksson's correct answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach doesn’t work for reasons explained by others. You can use something like this instead:

```js
var started = Date.now();
while(Date.now() - started < 1000) {
  console.log("aaa");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` is [asynchronous](https://medium.com/@moulayjam/what-is-settimeout-in-javascript-and-how-to-use-settimeout-synchronously-5653c5ffee3e#:%7E:text=setTimeout%20is%20asynchronous%3A&text=setTimeout%20is%20asynchronous%2C%20so%20the,will%20not%20wait%20for%20setTimeout.), so it will execute only after the current code execution of `for` loop completed. In your case it will go infinite.

Once for loop started execution, it will stay in the call stack until finished. Since you didn't give any condition there it won't stop